# Java OOP polymorphism design/issue

Tags: java, oop, polymorphism

I am creating a very basic `Cache` object. Here is my code:

`Cache.java` is an abstract class meant to be overriden.

```
public abstract class Cache {

    protected Date dateCreated;
    protected long expiration;
    private BuildStrategy strategy;

    protected Cache(long expiration, BuildStrategy strategy) {
        this.dateCreated = new Date();
        this.expiration = expiration;
        this.strategy = strategy;
        strategy.buildAndUpdate();
    }

    private final boolean isExpired() {
        long duration = new Date().getTime() - this.dateCreated.getTime();

        if (duration > expiration) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void build() {
        if (!isExpired())
            return;
        setDateCreated(new Date());
        buildAndUpdate();
    }

    protected abstract void buildAndUpdate();

    final Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    final void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    final long getExpiration() {
        return expiration;
    }

    final void setExpiration(long expiration) {
        this.expiration = expiration;
    }
}
```

This is a sample of a class that overrides it, `ACache.java`:

```
   public class ACache extends Cache {

    protected ACache(long expiration) {
        super(expiration);
    }

    private Object variableToBeUpdated;

    public Object getVariableToBeUpdated() {
        return variableToBeUpdated;
    }

    public void setVariableToBeUpdated(Object variableToBeUpdated) {
        this.variableToBeUpdated = variableToBeUpdated;
    }

    @Override
    protected void buildAndUpdate() {
        // ...connects to the database etc...
        // ...once database stuff is done, update variableToBeUpdated
        // NOTE: Other caches may implement buildAndUpdate() differently, that's
        // why it's abstract
    }
}
```

My problem here is that I want to hide the `buildAndUpdate()` method and just expose the `build()` method of `Cache` because in order for the `Cache` to be updated, I would want to check if it's expired first.

Since `buildAndUpdate()` is `protected`, the method can be accessed by the class itself. How do I proceed with what I want to do? How can you improve my implementation?

EDIT 1: Took ControlAltDel and Turing85's advice and went with IoC. I created an interface called `BuildStrategy` that has a `void buildAndUpdate()` method. Is this correct?

Comment: `buildAndUpdate` in the `Cache` class is abstract, so it cannot be called from `ACache`, if that's what you're worried about.

Comment: What? It totally can be called in `ACache`. `ACache` overrides the `buildAndUpdate()` method and since it's `protected abstract` in `Cache`, that means it would have the `protected` modifier when overriden in `ACache`  That's the problem.

Comment: Who consumes/uses a cache?  Only package level types or anyone?

Comment: I basically have another class that would manage all the caches. Yes, they're in the same package. `ACache.java`, `Cache.java`, `CacheManager.java` are all in the same package.

Comment: as a design tip, I would suggest you make your class generic

Comment: @Pranalee I just put `Object` there as pseudocode. An implementation of `Cache` would likely cache one or more variables.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal I meant that you cannot call `Cache`'s version of `buildAndUpdate`, since there is no implementation there. Of course `ACache` can call _its own_ implementation of that method, but why would that be a problem? Any class outside your cache package that doesn't subclass one of those classes will not be able to call `buildAndUpdate`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you could go would be to get rid of this method entirely, and instead create at BuildAndUpdate class, which would be a required parameter in the constructor. You could then subclass your Cache class, and in an empty constructor, initialize the superclass with a BuildAndUpdate object.

Make sense?

Comment: You mean [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)?

Comment: Hmm... I got lost at `...which would be a required parameter in the constructor.` I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @MiguelPortugal look at my link. Basically, you need to construct an management-object, which manages the `buildAndUpdate`-process of one particular `Cache` and pass this management-object into the `Cache` class (which should store it as an attribute for future use).

Comment: @Turing85 @ControlAltDel Please check my latest edit. I created an interface called `BuildStrategy` that has a `void buildAndUpdate()` method. So for every `Cache` that has a different `buildAndUpdate()` method, I should make a class that implements `BuildStrategy` right?

Comment: @MiguelPortugal Yes you got the idea

Answer (score 1):

you can use generics. Not sure why you need class to be abstract. People who require special behaviour, they can extend your class.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Map;

public  class  Cache<K,V> {
private Map<K,V> map;
protected Date dateCreated;
protected long expiration;

protected Cache(long expiration) {
    this.dateCreated = new Date();
    this.expiration = expiration;
    buildAndUpdate();
}

private final boolean isExpired(){
    long duration = new Date().getTime() - this.dateCreated.getTime();

    if (duration > expiration){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

protected void build(){
    if (!isExpired()) return;
    setDateCreated(new Date());
    buildAndUpdate();
}

protected void buildAndUpdate(){
    //populate map here
}

final Date getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

final void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
}

final long getExpiration() {
    return expiration;
}

final void setExpiration(long expiration) {
    this.expiration = expiration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is I moved the class that managed all the `Cache` objects in another package. I liked the idea of Inversion of Control though, makes the code looks smoother and modular - which is why I marked it as the best answer.